# Power Automate: Parse JSON Action: Schema Validation Failed

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Used the following article to check if a field changes:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Check-for-a-Change-in-a-SharePoint-List-Column-Value/ba-p/241347

The following is the error message in general:

> Action 'Parse_JSON' failed

The following is the internal actions error messages, more detailed.

```
[
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "d.results[1].Title",
    "schemaId": "#/properties/d/properties/results/items/properties/Title",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  },
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "d.results[1].Comments",
    "schemaId": "#/properties/d/properties/results/items/properties/Comments",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  },
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "d.results[1].EstimatedCompletionDate",
    "schemaId": "#/properties/d/properties/results/items/properties/EstimatedCompletionDate",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can fix the JSON schema by setting the property as nullable like below:

Instead of `"type": "string"` you can place `"type": ["string", "null"]`

[Read more](https://blog.thenetw.org/2019/03/11/quick-fix-microsoft-flow-error-invalid-type-expected-string-but-got-null/)

Comment: Thanks Arun. I appreciate it. I will try that.

Comment: You can also remove all the `"type"` key/value pairs from the JSON schema to prevent this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it : I removed the fields (in the JSON Schema) that the error message complained about and it fixed it. I was only interested in one field which is Status. The fields mentioned above (which is Title, Comments, and EstimatedCompletedDate) in the error message was not required to be filled in and hence gave this error.

The JSON Schema does not have to be exact, it can just be the Fields that you require and then those need to be filled in or required each time the form saves. Then it works.